# Free Charting Library for Visual C++ 2008

Tags: c++, winforms, charts

Can anybody suggest free charting libraries for Visual C++ 2008 Windows Forms Application.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx

Written in C#, can be used by any .NET language in Windows Forms.